# President Misleading Investors, Should Employees Tell?

Tags: management, contractors

I work in a small firm of 10 people, with one President who answers to a group of directors who are investors. They do not work in the office.

The board approved the President's hiring of his buddy as a consultant to assist the sales department.  According to the contract, this person's only job is to 'provide support to sales'.  It actually states that this person is a contractor, has no supervisory status, and goes on to list other things that are not in this person's scope. Like the things in the next paragraph.

Bottom line:  The President has handed operations over to his friend. Buddy has so far 'supervised' in every department (quite nastily, too), outsourced projects overseas, and ordered sweeping changes in all departments, and has business cards showing his title as Vice President.

Is it advisable for an employee or group to notify the directors about what's really going on?

Comment: Could you notify the directors anonymously? Send them a few of his business cards through the mail with no return address.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm not saying this is the case here, but sometimes peace of mind and of workplace is more important than job preservation.

Answer (score 4):

You should be careful about this and ask yourself the questions :

- What exactly I know about this guys activities?
- Do you know everything he is doing or just what other
  people complain about?
- What do you expect if you report this guy to
  the investor?
- What  influence it will have on your job if you report him? Do you risk to
  be fired?
- Do you think the actions of this guy put the company at
  risk?

Answer (score 4):

I was in this situation once.  It's very difficult place, and regardless what you choose to do, it will be stressful for you and your colleagues.

Some questions that you need to answer for yourself(selves) in order to make your options clearer:

How do you know what's in the buddy's contract?  Are you sure there isn't a second contract superseding it?

Has anyone pushed back against this person's supervision?  What was said?  What happened?

Has the buddy actually affected your ability to do your job?  Not 'nastily supervised', but overtly issued commands, or overruled previous decisions, such that you were less productive, or delivered poor quality products, or experienced reduced revenue and customer satisfaction?

Has the buddy caused the company to lose sales while he's busy doing these other things?

Are you sure this isn't what the directors wanted all along, but they didn't want to tell the staff upfront for some reason?

Answer these questions honestly, and hopefully you'll be able to choose between

- blow the whistle
- grit your teeth and put up with it
- get another job

If you do go to the investors, be specific, focus purely on the business, don't get emotional, and don't make it personal.  You are doing it for the good of the business and because you have a fiduciary duty.  You are not doing it because you're pissed off.

Also realize that if the buddy goes, then either the president will go too, or he will most likely try to take revenge on the whistleblowers.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

O U C H !

If you know how the contract is worded it probably only points to you or a couple people.

What you are asserting is not very believable. If the President is hiring the friend just to pay them then the friend would be keeping a low profile.

If this pseudo VP has gotten to the point of outsourced projects overseas the party is over or the investors are in on the party.

Time to lay low and put out your resume.

Comment: It sounds like the president basically hired the guy to do his job.  I've seen it happen, although it was the boss' wife (the boss was disabled at that point) that brought in the outsider that did tons of damage.  Whether the company could have survived 2008 without that I don't know, with that their downfall was inevitable.